# Django: how do I use object from a previous form to filter object?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
def Date_Form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']

            date1 = DateOptions.objects.get(date=date)
            flight_date = Flight.objects.filter(date_options=date1)

            form1 = KeyWordForm(request.POST)

            return render(request, 'app/index.html',{'flight_date': flight_date, 'date': date, 'form1': form1})

    else:
        form = DateForm()

    return render(request, 'app/options.html', {'form':form})


def Search_Destination(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form1 = KeyWordForm(request.POST)

        if form1.is_valid():
            destination = form1.cleaned_data['destination'].capitalize()

            result= Flight.objects.filter(destination__icontains=destination, date_options=????)

            return render(request, 'app/search.html', {'result':result, 'destination':destination})

    else: 
        form1 = KeyWordForm()

    return render(request, 'app/searchfield.html', {'form1':form1})
```

This part is where I struggle:

```
result= Flight.objects.filter(destination__icontains=destination, date_options=????)
```

I want to be able to use the same date_option as date1. I know I can't say date_options=date1. The system won't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `session` to store the pk when first use the `date1` instance

```
date1 = DateOptions.objects.get(date=date)
flight_date = Flight.objects.filter(date_options=date1)
# Set the session variable
request.session['date1_pk'] = date1.pk
```

And in your second view, you will retrieve the `pk`, and filter with it

```
result= Flight.objects.filter(destination__icontains=destination, 
            date_options__pk=request.session.pop('date1_pk'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I am going to answer my own question. Lol I just found the answer. I need to define date1 as a global object so that Python recognizes the object all around the scope.

```
def Date_Form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            global date1
            date1 = DateOptions.objects.get(date=date)
            flight_date = Flight.objects.filter(date_options=date1)

            form1 = KeyWordForm(request.POST)

            return render(request, 'app/index.html',{'flight_date': flight_date, 'date': date, 'form1': form1})

    else:
        form = DateForm()

    return render(request, 'app/options.html', {'form':form})


def Search_Destination(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form1 = KeyWordForm(request.POST)

        if form1.is_valid():
            destination = form1.cleaned_data['destination'].capitalize()

            result= Flight.objects.filter(destination__icontains=destination, date_options=date1)

            return render(request, 'app/search.html', {'result':result, 'destination':destination})

    else: 
        form1 = KeyWordForm()

    return render(request, 'app/searchfield.html', {'form1':form1})
```

Comment: No, you must absolutely **not** do this. This is not at all safe in a multi-user environment like a web app.

Comment: Because the variable is shared by all users.

Comment: Pass the variable in the URL, or store it in the session.